# REFrostedViewController pan gesture disables tableview swipe

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I used REFrostedViewController for menu and in the main screen uitableview is to display the list and I've added swipe to delete in uitableviewcell... UITableviewcell swipe is not working because of pan gesture in REFrostedViewController. How to fix this? Can't we have both pan gesture and swipe in the same view?

I tried disabling the pan gesture with this code

```
self.frostedView.panGestureEnabled = false;
```

but tableview swipe is not working

Answer (score 0):

**SWTableViewCell** has all the options you might want.

While **UITableviewcell** native swipe is not working sometimes. You can try with **SWTableViewCell**.

Full details on how to implement are in this link: [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)